# Add more features to stack container

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I am using default features(push, pop, top, empty, size) of stack container of STL. If I want to add more features like access an element from middle of stack.

How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't. That's not what a stack is. If you want a more powerful container, use a different container. Like `std::vector`.

Comment: One of the reasons someone might choose to use a stack is that it implies the need for a certain set of operations, giving the reader of the code some hint of the algorithms that may be used . It also implies the ability to switch to another implementation of a stack (for example, to see if it performs better or uses less memory). If you have some kind of "power stack" that goes beyond the expected interface, you've invalidated both those implications and will confuse reviewers/maintainers of the code.

Comment: stack by default use deques for its implementation but only gives 5 features to use. Can I make a generic container for stack?

Comment: Knowing `std::deque` is underlying `std::stack`, why don't you just use `std::deque`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is interview question or something, and you have to do it anyways, you can do this like, below code. derive from `std::stac`, and overload `operator[]`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class myStack:public std::stack<T>
{
    public:
        T operator[](long index)
        {
            std::stack<T> temp;
            T tempVal;
            for(long i=0;i<index;++i)
            {
                if(this->template empty())
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
                tempVal = this->template  top();
                temp.push(tempVal);
                this->template pop();
            }

            //T retVal = this->template top();
            while(!temp.empty())
            {
                T tempVal = temp.top();
                this->template push(tempVal);
                temp.pop();
            }

            return tempVal;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    myStack<int> st;

    st.push(5);
    st.push(1);
    st.push(7);
    st.push(9);
    st.push(4);

    std::cout<<"3rd Element :"<<st[3]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if it's not an interview question?

Comment: If its for real world problems , i would suggest not to use stack for random access or something , use vector instead.